# Selecting text in ionic should trigger an event ? how?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Well it has been done in JS, and I did it on the web version of my app using JS
How do I do same for android app.
What I essentially want is that I'd select text in my ionic app, and when I do so, I'd expect to get an option of 'Highlight' the text , and then the text gets saved in a variable which I can use further
Essentially  it is a note taking app, where I highlight the text
I did it using TinyQ in js, but how to do it in ionic
All the efforts are appretiated

Comment: Check this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-le257o?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thanks for the reply, it works like a charm
But would it work in the android app?

Comment: I haven't tested it on  Android or Real Device. but it Should Work. Give it a try.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib it worked in android but is extremely slow

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib please post it as answer so taht I'd accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Selected text you can use:

`window.getSelection().toString()`

Check Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-le257o?file=src/app/app.component.ts):